# Data projection to CRS taking extremely long time in cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I am using cartopy to plot data on top of satellite image tiles, but transforming my data to a CRS that lines up on top of the map takes an extremely long time (currently 1hr plus). The two datasets I am trying to plot is a tripcolor with 560000 triangles and a pcolormesh with 1000 x 1600 cells. Is there a different strategy I could use?

The code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

mapbox = cimgt.MapboxTiles(access_token = token, map_id = 'satellite-v9')


ax = plt.axes(projection=mapbox.crs)
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.add_image(mapbox, 13)
#ax.tripcolor(triangulation, z_tri, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(np.log(z), cmap = cmap, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this specific to Cartopy? How long does it take if you reproject the data upfront? Is the level of detail in the data actually showing up in the image? Some pre-processing, either downsampling or rasterizing the data could help without impacting final quality.